# How to stop video recording upon changing views

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an AVFoundation video recording capture session that starts and stops/saves by tapping a start/stop icon. I need the recording session to stop and save automatically upon changing to an alternate view (such as a flipside view or another storyboard view) if recording was not stopped manually by tapping the stop icon prior to changing to the alternate view. I have the following code but recording continues through the view change and while in the alternate view. I would appreciate a specific coding solution since I am new to this. Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.videoProcessor = nil;

    [self.videoProcessor stopAndTearDownCaptureSession];
    self.videoProcessor.delegate = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.videoProcessor stopAndTearDownCaptureSession];
    self.videoProcessor.delegate = nil;

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could place the code inside the `viewWillDisappear` method of your view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
    [super viewWillDisappear];

    [self.videoProcessor stopAndTearDownCaptureSession];
    self.videoProcessor.delegate = nil;
    self.videoProcessor = nil;
}
```

The `viewDidUnload` method only gets called when your application is running out of memory, so it will try to unload any views not currently being displayed.

Comment: Thank you. This now hangs in my saveMovieToCameraRoll. How do I allow the capture session to finish saving? This is what I have to finish saving when it is backgrounded: `if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) backgroundRecordingID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}];`